# django template won't load css and javascript files

Tags: css, django, django-forms, django-views

I am creating an application in django and everything works great, except one template. all the template load the javascript and css files with any problem, but there's one template doen't load any css or JS file.
When I am typing the view of this template I make an typo error and after I fix it the template won't load any css or JS file

**UPDATE: View definition indented**
view

```
@permission_required('prov.views.configView',login_url='/login/')
def MasterFormView(request):
    form = MasterForm(request.POST or None)
    if request.method == 'POST':
       idp = request.POST['id_proveedor']
       a = request.POST['anio']
       m = request.POST['mes']
       id = Proveedor.objects.get(id_proveedor=idp)
       obj,created = Master.objects.get_or_create(id_proveedor=id,anio=a,mes=m)
       if form.is_valid(): 
          objdetrec,createddetrec = DetalleRecepcion.objects.get_or_create(id_proveedor=id,anio=a,mes=m)
          objdetcar,createddetcar = DetalleCargaArchivo.objects.get_or_create(id_proveedor=id,anio=a,mes=m)
          objdetcon,createddetcon = DetalleConci.objects.get_or_create(id_proveedor=id,anio=a,mes=m)
          objenvcon,createdenvcon = EnvioConci.objects.get_or_create(id_proveedor=id,anio=a,mes=m)
          objcer,createdcer = Certificado.objects.get_or_create(id_proveedor=id,anio=a,mes=m)
          objentcert,createdentcert = EntCertificado.objects.get_or_create(id_proveedor=id,anio=a,mes=m)
          objacepta,createdacepta = AceptCertificado.objects.get_or_create(id_proveedor=id,anio=a,mes=m)
          objrepro,createdrepro = Reproceso.objects.get_or_create(id_proveedor=id,anio=a,mes=m)
          return HttpResponseRedirect('/monitor/')

       if not created:
          obj.id_proveedor = id
          obj.anio = a
          obj.mes = m
          #-----------------------------
          objdetrec.id_proveedor = id
          objdetrec.anio = a
          objdetrec.mes = m
          #----------------------------
          objdetcar.id_proveedor = id
          objdetcar.anio = a
          objdetcar.mes = m
          #----------------------------
          objdetcon.id_proveedor = id
          objdetcon.anio = a
          objdetcon.mes = m
          #----------------------------
          objenvcon.id_proveedor = id
          objenvcon.anio = a
          objenvcon.mes = m
          #----------------------------
          objcer.id_proveedor = id
          objcer.anio = a
          objcer.mes = m
          #----------------------------
          objentcert.id_proveedor = id
          objentcert.anio = a
          objentcert.mes = m
          #----------------------------
          objacepta.id_proveedor = id
          objacepta.anio = a
          objacepta.mes = m
          #----------------------------
          objrepro.id_proveedor = id
          objrepro.anio = a
          objrepro.mes = m
          #----------------------------
          obj.save()
          objdetrec.save()
          objdetcar.save()
          objdetcon.save()
          objenvcon.save()
          objcer.save()
          objentcert.save()
          objacepta.ave()
          objrepro.save()
          return HttpResponseRedirect('/monitor/')
    return render_to_response('masterform.html',
                              {'form':form})
```

form:

```
class MasterForm(forms.ModelForm):
      def __init__(self,*args,**kwargs):
       super(MasterForm,self).__init__(*args,**kwargs)
       self.helper = FormHelper(self)
       self.helper.layout.append(Submit('save','Grabar'))
       self.helper.layout = Layout(
        Fieldset('',
                 'id_proveedor',
                 'anio',
                 'mes',
                 Submit('save','Grabar'),
                )
       )

      class Meta:
        model = Master
```

url:

```
 url(r'^masterform/$', 'prov.views.MasterFormView',name='masterform'),
```

The form update all the models specified and works fine, but doesn't have style or JS functions.

I don't know why all the others template can load the css files and this form don't
Anybody have the same issue or any idea how to fix this.

P.D.: in firebug the error is "PAGE NOT FOUND"

**UPDATE Add the code of the html templates**
masterform.html

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}
{% load crispy_forms_tags %}

{% block content %}
<div class="container">
<div class="col-sm-4"
<form method='POST' action='' class='form'>
   <div class="form-group">
        {% csrf_token %}
        {% crispy form  %}
   </div>
</form>
</div>
</div>
{% endblock %}
```

base.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
   <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="author" content="">
    <link rel="icon" href="../../favicon.ico">
    <title>Proveedores de Contenido</title>

    <!-- Bootstrap core CSS -->
     <link href="{{STATIC_URL|default:"/static/"}}admin/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
     <link href="{{STATIC_URL|default:"/static/"}}admin/css/custom.css" rel="stylesheet">
     <link href="{{STATIC_URL|default:"/static/"}}admin/css/jquery.dataTables.css" rel="stylesheet">
     <link href="{{STATIC_URL|default:"/static/"}}admin/css/customtable.css" rel="stylesheet">
     <link href="{{STATIC_URL|default:"/static/"}}admin/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

     <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
     <script src="{{STATIC_URL|default:"/static/"}}admin/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
     <!-- script type="text/javascript" src="/static/admin/js/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script -->
     <script src="{{STATIC_URL|default:"/static/"}}admin/js/jquery.dataTables.js"></script>
     <script src="{{STATIC_URL|default:"/static/"}}admin/js/dataTables.bootstrap.js"></script>
  </head>

 <body>
{% block content %}{% endblock %}
{% include 'footer.html'%}

  </body>
</html>
```

When I create the viwe, form and template works fine and load every css and js file.
Later I make a change and accidentally type wrong some word. After I fix the typo error is the template won't load my css and js files.
But the form works fine, only don't have style.
I am thinking in rewrite all (view, form, htmltemplates and change the url) and see if there some corrupt file or configuration

Answer (score 0):

It seems like your redirecting yourself to the masterform.html. This is where css and javascript are loaded.

**Edit:**

The files cant be found because you haven't the correct settings:

For app:
`STATIC_URL = '/static/'`

For prodject:`STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static"),
    '/var/www/static/',
)`

add these two settings to your settings file and dont forget to load them:
`{% load  staticfiles %}`

at the top of all your html files.

Then you will not need your `{{STATIC_URL | default}}` anymore just use `{{ STATIC_URL}}`

[Manage static files](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/howto/static-files/)

**Suggestion:**

Make a `{%block exta_head %} {% endblock %}`
inside your  of your main template so your extended templates can add there own files.

Comment: I indent the code and I still can't load the css or the js files. see the update

Comment: Can you post your masterform.html. In the head part of your html file there should be links to js files and css files

Comment: I added the definition of two template the masterform.html and base.html. the masterform template extend the base template